# N-order differential equations

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, laplace-transform

Suppose that we have n-order differential equation like $$h(x)=?$$
Is it possible to find a general solution for all n?
$$(x^n+1).|h'(x)|^n=const.$$.

Answer (score 1):

If I properly understand, you look for the solution of $$h'(x)=\frac k{(1+x^n)^{1/n}}$$ The solution exists but it involves  [the hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $$h(x)= k x \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n};1+\frac{1}{n};-x^n\right)+C$$

The only simple forms are $$n=1 \implies h(x)=k \,\log (1+x)+C$$  $$n=2 \implies h(x)=k\, \sinh ^{-1}(x)+C$$

Don't be afraid since, sooner or later, you will learn about it.

Comment: what is the for n=4 ?

Comment: This is the notation of the hypergeometric function $_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n};1+\frac{1}{n};-x^n\right)$

Comment: For $n>2$, I do not see any possible expression beside the  hypergeometric function.

Comment: thanks for your respond. You mean there is not any solution for n>2 ?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you I am really  far from this :)

Comment: No expressions in terms of elementary functions. Don't worry : you don't bother me at all and you are welcome.

Comment: tnx for your wisdom

Comment: The particular parameters in the hypergeometric function allow to reduce it to a special function of lower level : the Incomplete Beta function. My greetings to Claude Leibovici.